# Which mean and standard error should be used when standardizing a variable coming from a different data set?

Tags: standardization

I'm leveraging data from the Census Bureau's ACS 5 year summary data, which includes point estimates and margin of error for variables at the census tract level.  For example, the median income for census tract 1234 may be estimated at 60,000 and the margin of error for this estimate is provided at 3,000.  This data set is being joined to a list of individuals based on which census tract they live in.  Ultimately a regression analysis is being completed to understand the relationship between these regional attributes and a dependent variable of the individual.  I'd like to center and scale these variables prior to completing the regression.  I see two options for making this calculation and I am unclear as to which is correct:

1. Use the point estimate provided in the ACS data files as the mean and calculate the standard error from the provided margin of error (n is given and the CV is also published) to standardize by tract, prior to joining.  In other words, use the mean and standard error of the population coming from within each census tract--each tract would be standardized independently.
2. Calculate the mean values and standard error of these variables after joining to the data set of individuals.  In other words, use the mean and standard error of the individuals being analyzed across census tracts--all tracts would be standardized collectively, based on the individuals who are to be included in the regression.

Comment: Please explain what you hope to accomplish through the centering and scaling of the variables.  It's unnecessary in many cases.

Comment: I would like to have all variables on the same scale so I can compare coefficients and rank the importance of the variables in the model.

Comment: It sounds like (but not completely clear) that you have some variables at a county level and some at an individual level. If this is so, you will violate the assumption of independent errors and need to do something like GEE or a multilevel model.

Comment: @Peter, do you mean that you can't use, for example, year-level covariates along with day-level covariates in the same regression?